# pandas convert timestamp in a dynamic way

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe which is having the following timestamps. Total of 5600000 rows!

```
time                                   SD
2016-01-02 11:23:04.299000+00:00       1
2016-02-02 11:23:04.299000+00:00       2
2016-03-02 11:23:04.299000+00:00       2
2016-04-01 11:23:04.299000+00:00       3
```

Because I am doing the following operation, it throws an error.

`(TypeError: Timestamp subtraction must have the same timezones or no timezones)`

```
(pd.to_datetime("2016-01-02 11:23:04.299000+00:00") - pd.Timestamp("1970-01-01"))
```

Here i know the problem, and it could be solved by `(pd.to_datetime("2016-01-02 11:23:04") - pd.Timestamp("1970-01-01"))`

I am looking for an optimized solution for this problem because i think it is not a good way to iterate all rows of "time", it takes a lot of time.

there might be a change that i get different format than what i have right now in the dataframe.

is there anything i can do with "pandas"?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC This will use numpy and pandas to get the data difference between the 2 columns without the second column having the timezones

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'], infer_datetime_format = True)
df['date_to_subtract'] = pd.to_datetime('1970-01-01')
df['difference'] = df['time'].values - df['date_to_subtract'].values
```

Comment: so it will make a difference for each row?  the difference i put there, it will apply for individual rows, this is not just for one timestamp. :)   E.g.  I get this `Timedelta('16802 days 11:23:04')` from the operation i mention above

Comment: Could you add a little more data to your original post? It may or may not based on your data, but if you could provide a varied and larger data set I would be happy to test/troubleshoot

Comment: its just time stamps. what is the confusion? could you ask plz!

Comment: My friend, I am trying to help you with your programing for free. I need as much information as possible to ensure that you get the results you are expecting...Anyways, as long as the portion after the + is the same throughout the dataframe then yes it should get you the date difference between the first and second column

Comment: yes, Thank you. I can add more details.   i used this operation `df[time[i]] - pd.Timestamp("1970-01-01"))   where i -0,1,2,3,4` . I simplified in my post.    it is a difference of each timestamps.

Comment: hey, so your suggestion works. in the 'difference' column I get values (16802 days 11:23:04.299000). Can I get rid of ".299000"? is it possible?

Comment: You could add a df['difference'] = df['difference'].apply(lambda x : str(x).split('.')[0]) to the end of it, but unfortunately, that would change it from a timedelta to a string if that would be acceptable.